# "takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given" when using click library (invoke function)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python script using the "click" library to run various actions. In the below code, I attempted to use a pre-existing function in a new function. I tried to follow the click documentation to use the Context invoke and forward (which seems to work). But I get the error on execution of the make_connection function: "use_connection() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given". I am unsure what I'm doing wrong here. Please help.

```
from click.core import Context
import pysftp
import click
...

@click.group()
def cli():
    pass


@cli.command('make_connection')
def make_connection():
    return pysftp.Connection(server, username=username, password=sftp_key)


@cli.command('use_connection')
@click.pass_context
def use_connection():
    Context.forward(make_connection)
    connection = Context.invoke(make_connection)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli()
```

Comment: is this function in a class? and you calling it by class object or class name?

Comment: Good question. The functions are not in a class. They're in a "click" group. I've edited my example above to elaborate on this.

I'm following the "Invoking other commands" section from here. I don't get errors on invoking the command but I think I'm missing something silly.
https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/advanced/?highlight=click%20context

Comment: just add a variable in `use_connection` , something like `def use_connection(temp)` and tell me if that works.

Comment: @cli.command('use_connection')
@click.argument('temp')
@click.pass_context
def use_connection(temp):
    Context.forward(make_connection)
    connection = Context.invoke(make_connection)

Comment: yes, execute your program and tell me if that works

Comment: Looks like I  entered my previous comment prematurely. Sorry.
I attempted to use a dummy variable as suggested. 
Code below (click.argument is way to declare parameter for the following click function). When executing below code, now I get below error:
use_connection() got multiple values for argument 'temp'

It seems that there's a variable being entered already. And now we have "multiple".

@cli.command('use_connection') @click.argument('temp') 
@click.pass_context 

def use_connection(temp): 
    Context.forward(make_connection) 
    connection = Context.invoke(make_connection)

Comment: fine, we will play its way,  try `def use_connection(*temp)`

Comment: no luck :(
TypeError: use_connection() got an unexpected keyword argument 'temp'

Comment: strange, temp is a positional argument

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `cli()` like this:

```
def cli(ctx):
    ...
```

A context obj is passed to cli as a first argument.